# What is the best method to detect duplicate row on mysql and add new values to specific row

Tags: php, mysql

i am currently working on a site which get video content from other websites.
My script gets the new videos from categories pages. There are also videos which are listed on 2 or more categories. Over a unique index i can detect when the url is the same but i wished to know how i could get in my category field more then 1 category id. I know how to do this but using php but this would mean i need 3 querys in order to update the field. There would be more than 3 - 4 millions entrys and almost every entry belongs to 2 or 3 diferrent categories.

Is there a way like "ON DUPLICATE KEY add to category_field category id 3"
so i would end up with a row like: category_field(2,3,100,45,9) only by using mysql AND detect before adding the new category id to the field if the category id already exists in it?

Thank you very much. I hope i could make myself clear enough english is not my native language.

Comment: First off, you should normalize the categories and not try to store a comma delimited list in a column. IOW, don't store multiple foreign keys in a column. Create a table to hold the video key and the category key, and add a unique index on those two columns. As you add a new video, you would insert into this linking table. If the video/category already exists, the insert will fail, and all will be right with the world :-), but if it succeeds, the video is now linked to the category.

Comment: BTW, with the multi-key column you describe, what if you try to add a key that is already there? Think of the processor load of not just adding a key, but preventing duplicate keys in that column. What if a video is in so many categories that the list gets truncated?

Comment: i cannot save the categories in a table because i dont know how many categories are. The categories are created on the fly.. every page has its own category name so when there are new categories found they will be created and stored in each website row. Its a little bit tricky but i need this in order to correctly return results when filtered by categories using sphinx.

Comment: Are the categories strictly just numbers, or are there category names with the numbers? One of the best arguments for using a category table with a many-to-many linking table is in your first sentence: *"because I don't know how many categories there are"*. If you want to be able to search by category ID, the performance will be much better searching the category table for the name joined with the many-to-many table and the video table.